# ¿Cómo aplicar un evento onclick de javascript a ciertas coordenadas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero hacer que al momento de dar `clic` en algunas coordenadas de mi sistema este active un mensaje, pero me gustaría que sea en cualquier parte de mi sistema sin necesidad de que haya un elemento de por medio, solo con ingresar en que punto y las dimensiones que abarcara dicho punto que ejecutara mi evento de `javascript` o `jquery`. Actualmente no tengo código disponible porque no se como realizarlo ni como iniciar.

Comment: te refieres a eventos de mouse?

Comment: @x-rw, si me refiero a los eventos que el mouse puede hacer con cooredenadas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por si solo a toda la pantalla no es posible, lo que puedes hacer es crear un div del tamaño de tu pantalla, y aplicar los eventos de posición

```js
function getPos(e){
      x=e.clientX;
      y=e.clientY;
      cursor="tu posicion es X: " + x + " and Y " + y ;
  
            if(x<=100 && y<100){
              alert("hacer algo");
            }
      console.log(cursor)
     }
    
     function parar(){
      console.log("");
     }
```

```css
#total{
width:530px;
height:313px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body onmousemove="getPos(event)" onmouseout="parar()"> 
<div id="total" > mostrar Height / Width </div> 
<p id="resultado"></p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: en el editor de snippets hay un botón que identa el código :D

Comment: @EmanuelVe a que te refieres con identar?

Comment: al espacio entre el borde izquierdo y el codigo. Es el boton "Ordenar"

Comment: @EmanuelVe uff muchas gracias lo tomare en cuenta!!!

Comment: Muy buena respuesta :-)

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo muchas gracias !!!